# c# timer doesn't wait

Tags: c#, timer

I'm trying to run a function every 5 minutes, for some reason the timer doesn't wait at all, everything happens instantly.
This is the code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        setTimer();
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static void callProcedure(object state)
    {
        //dosomething..

        setTimer();
    }

    private static void setTimer()
    {
        System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(callProcedure, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x96zfy7(v=vs.110).aspx should answer your question, especially the "remarks" section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see an infinite loop. When you create a timer, it executes the `callProcedure` once at `TimeSpan.Zero`, and then again every 5 minutes, the last parameter to the constructor.

So when you create the timer, it automatically executes the function, which creates the exact same timer again, which runs the `callProcedure` instantly, so on so forth. It will never end.

Just swap your last 2 arguments around, to make it run only once every 5 minutes, to reset the timer to run again in another 5 minutes.

```
System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
    callProcedure, null, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), TimeSpan.Zero);
```